# php, checking correctnes of text splitting

Tags: php, text, split

I need to split **html document** on two parts. First part, should contain N(30) words, and next one should contain everything else.
And the main problem, is to prevent splitting tags (description and body of tags).

1. `<a **<=>** href="text" > text </a>`
2. `<a href="text" > **<=>** text </a>`
3. `<a href="text" > text </ **<=>** a>`

Give me please suggestions (or if you have already written such function, please share your code), how to realize it! Thanks.

Comment: I misread that as "Spelling" first time round, then read the title... then glared and decided not to edit it because it was just funnier that way. Now I realise it wasn't spelling. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM Parser, documentation you can find at http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

You can parse your html in a tree with this class, and get your result by tree manipulation and saving your data.